# display current and next record side by side during ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6

I am really stuck on this one. Basically I have data that looks like this:

```
[{'name':'Bank A', movements:[{'direction':'Direct','amount':6000,'client':'A'}, {'direction':'InDirect','amount':-5800,'client':'A'}, {'direction':'Direct','amount':5800,'client':'B'},
{'direction':'InDirect','amount':-5500,'client':'B'},
{'direction':'Direct','amount':5500,'client':'B'}]
```

Banks B, C etc have similar data structure as well.

Now, what I want it in the following fashion (just 'movements' block):

```
 Client    Direct     Indirect Amount
   A        6000      -5800    200
   B        5800      -5500   300
   B        5500       0      5500
```

Last element is always 0 indirect. As well, if it is only one element, indirect is 0.

What I have tried so far (but failed nor is elegant).

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="result.movements.length==1">
   <tr>
    <td>{{result.movements[0].clientName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.movements[0].amount}}</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>{{result.movements[0].amount}}</td>
   </tr>
 </ng-container>

 <ng-container *ngIf="result.movements.length>1">
   <tr *ngFor="let i of Array(result.movements.length-1)>
    <td>{{result.movements[i].clientName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.movements[i].amount}}</td>
    <td>{{result.movements[i+1].amount}}</td>
    <td>{{{{result.movements[i].direct + result.movements[i+1].amount}}}}</td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>{{result.movements[result.movements.length-1].clientName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.movements[result.movements.length-1].amount}}</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>{{result.movements[result.movements.length-1].amount}}</td>
   </tr
```

My idea was to represent the collection as an array, loop until the 2nd last then display the very last outside `*ngFor`.

What would be the ideal way?

Comment: using `mat-table` to create this same table is not an option?

Comment: I am not that familiar with mat-table to begin with. But do you think what mat-table can do can't be done with normal table or div element? I also feel it is more of a logic issue more than elements but i am a starter to judge

Comment: Well its's more a thing of the best component for the task, I think if you are going to create a table with data, `mat-table` is the best option since it does a lot of the job for you, and then you can focus on the more specific things; `mat-table` logic is really good and there's few things you outright can't do

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional operator, let i=index and let last=last, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

```
<tr *ngFor="let movement of result.movements;let i=index;let last=last>
    <td>{{movement.clientName}}</td>
    <td>{{movement.amount}}</td>
    <td>{{last?0:result.movements[i+1].amount}}</td>
    <td>{{last?movement.direct:movement.direct + result.movements[i+1].amount}}</td>
</tr>
```